# How to change the permission of a file for an application in os x?

Tags: macos, file, permissions, itunes, id3-tag

I run an application in OS X Mavericks, specifically a music application which opens mp3 files and, here comes my problem, in some way *writes* the metadata of the file, the ID3 Tag.
I manage my entire music library on the iTunes Media/Music folder, and I have all the files (+10000) carefully and completely tagged (I work on music) in iTunes, writing in the ID3 metadata of the files.
Now as I'm studying software engineering I'm developing a program to manage my library in the way I want.

The problem is that **every time** I open a mp3 file with my music application, it changes the ID3 tag trying to replace it with the information that *you can* edit inside the music application. This application **always** do this, there is no option to not allow to edit the metadata of the mp3s.

So, I want to protect all my files from that, changing the permission to 'only read' when opened with this application. I know this is simple in Windows, cause you can create an user and ban to only read permission of the mp3s by being executed of a program which is on other user than the file.
But in OS X i can't do that, because another user is another user account (for login in the system) and i don't want that! It can't be the solution.

Thanks in advance, I hope I explained well (i'm not english native).

Note: in this Music application, although I don't edit the metadata of the file, the app changes the ID3 tag by *strange trash in some bytes* (i don't know more why this), because in my program I advice that when I look into them, but iTunes doesn't, cause it saves also the metadata in the iTunes library file, an xml file.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove write permissions from files you own (and restore them later, if you want). From the command line, `chmod u-w filename` ; or, from the Finder, do Get Info, scroll down to Sharing & Permissions, and click on the Privilege box for your user. (To restore writability from the command line, `chmod u+w filename` .)

Comment: I now I can do this, but the problem is that I want to restringe the write permissions only for a specific program. Just in the case of your solution, how could I code a shell script to change the permissions for a set of files in order to do it each time I open and close the program?